# docker login stopped working

Tags: docker

I was playing around with docker & docker-desktop last week. I successfully did a (cmdline) docker login to our gitlab registry using an accesstoken I created and managed to pull some of our images.

Checking my ~/.docker/config.json I can see the 'auths' entry - however when I now try either 'docker login' or 'docker logout' it gives me an error stating

> err: exit status 1, out: `error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out:` pass not initialized: exit status 1: Error: password store is empty. Try "pass init".``

why is this not working now?

Edit: I removed ~/.docker after which 'docker login' and 'docker logout' work again (repeatedly). Only to find some time later that it has stopped working and it throws that error again.